Difference between passing CLI parameters and read parameters
If I give a bash script a parameter on the command line, I can use this as the value later in the script. However, if I query the same string with read, I get a different value.
Example:
./test.sh utrre$fdg.dsf88^
#!/bin/bash
var=$1
read -e "Enter password: " test

if [ "$var" = "$test" ]; then
  echo "Password match"
else
  echo "Password not match"
fi

But I always get Password not match. I assume this is because there are special signs in the string. How can I have both matching?

Command line parameter must be quoted with single quotes in your case,
For more details: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html

echo utrre.dsf88^ | ./script utrre$fdg.dsf88^ works, but you should understand why the argument to echo omits the $fdg.  You can also do: echo 'utrre$fdg.dsf88^' | ./script 'utrre$fdg.dsf88^'

@NahuelFouilleul : In an assignment, the RHS does not need to be quoted if it is just a parameter expansion.  Try x="a b c"; y=$x; echo "$y"

@Angled: You can debug this kind of errors easily by running your script with bash -x ./test.sh utrre$fdg.dsf88^.

The issue is when you call the script:
./test.sh utrre$fdg.dsf88^

$ is a special character that is interpreted by the shell as a variable.
Since $fdg likely does not exist, your script receives utrre.dsf88^ as parameter.
You could check it by added echo "var=$var" after setting the variable and see for yourself
To fix your issue, use simple quote to prevent variable expansion when call test.sh:
./test.sh 'utrre$fdg.dsf88^'

Also, I think there is a typo in the scrip:
read -sp "Enter password: " test  # -p to set prompt instead of -e / -s to hide password
echo # with -s, no new line is inserted so add it here

